# Wifi works, ssh can connect, but cannot connect out to the internet, cannot ping internal machines

Tags: networking, wireless, wifi, dhcp, wpa

I have a strange configuration problem with Wifi. When I connect a ethernet cable to my router, network eth0 is configured and I can access all internet resources.

However when I use a Wifi dongle, I can ssh into the Pi, but connection to the internet does not work, not even the router is reachable via ping. I have tried various combinations of settings in /etc/network/interfaces, but nothing makes it work nicely.

How can it work via eth0 and not over wlan0? Is there any option I can change to make this work better? Anything that could be misconfigured on the router? I have multiple other devices using Wifi on it without any problem...

This is the content of the config-files and output of some apps, any others that could shed some light on my problem?

```
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse b8:27:eb:42:36:d2
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metrik:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 64:70:02:29:47:55
          inet Adresse:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maske:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:125 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:69 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX bytes:31342 (30.6 KiB)  TX bytes:11574 (11.3 KiB)
```

```
 $ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"dodoli"  Nickname:""
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: F4:EC:38:B5:BF:BE
          Bit Rate:150 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=100/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

```
$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface default inet dhcp
```

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

```
$ route -n
Kernel-IP-Routentabelle
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="XXXXX"
        scan_ssid=1
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        psk="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
}
```

ping to 192.168.1.1 (i.e. the route) times out, however ping to my desktop machine from where I ssh into it works, but the connection is done across the router!

Comment: btw, I saw http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6644/wifi-dongle-cannot-ping-beyond-intranet-works-with-ethernet, but it talks about route not being set, but as far as I see I have set it correctly in my case.

Comment: Could you add the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: I have added the contents of the file

Comment: Do you have any other devices that use the WiFi on the same router okay?

Comment: Yes, I use an Android Tablet, a Laptop and previously had other devices connected as well. Also I can ssh into the machine via Wifi, i.e. "Laptop->LAN->Router->Raspberry via Wifi" works fine, so basic wifi setup seems to work, or?

Answer (score 5):

I found my answer here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=31238

Basically, it suggests you try this to "see where the internet connections stops":

```
traceroute www.raspberrypi.org
```

or to check if it is the DNS that fails

```
traceroute 93.93.128.176
```

For me, the first command failed but the second succeeded, so I added this to my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.254 8.8.8.8
```

(Use your router IP instead of the first one, the second is Google's public DNS.)

Worked like a charm after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what your issue is, but I thought I would so you my settings which appear to work fine (talks to the internet happily with Ethernet, WiFi, or even both attached). The settings were taken when only the WiFi was attached.

ifconfig is basically the same

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:cd:b8:08
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 80:1f:02:4b:76:b6
          inet addr:192.168.0.202  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:655 errors:0 dropped:721 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:91189 (89.0 KiB)  TX bytes:27707 (27.0 KiB)
```

iwconfig is basically the same

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:"NomNomNom"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.427 GHz  Access Point: 08:76:FF:2E:47:69
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=97/100  Signal level=57/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

/etc/network/interfaces is somewhat different for the wlan0 section. In particular it is set to manual rather than dhcp, and uses wpa-roam rather than wpa-conf.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/network/interfaces
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.198
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

/etc/resolv.conf has a couple of extra lines, not entirely sure what they do

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain config
search config
nameserver 192.168.0.1
```

route -n is basically the same

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf only differs in the network setup, this is probably due to different WiFi setups

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="NomNomNom"
        psk="************************"
        proto=RSN
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
        pairwise=TKIP
        auth_alg=OPEN
}
```

Hopefully one of the differences is the problem, not entirely sure which to try though...

Comment: Thanks, but I think I tried every possible combination of these before, with the one from your Pi the WiFi stays unassociated and nohting I do brings it into basic connected state in the first place: $ iwconfig
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"

Comment: I have now spent a lot of time adjusting the settings this way and that way, but nothing seems to have any effect. Either Wifi does not work at all or it works, but does not do dns and access to the internet. Without a way to actually diagnose the problem I fear I must give up here...

Comment: Have you changed / set any firewall settings on the Pi?

Comment: No, didn't change the base raspberry in any other way than to set up the Wifi-Dongle. And connecting via eth0/LAN works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I replaced:
auto wlan0
with:
iface wlan0 inet manual

After reboot the probem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, ssh, vnc (remote desktop) and any communication PC --> RPI was working fine, but running sudo apt-get update or pinging any host or opening a website from the Pi did not work.

Network connection was only Wifi.

It appear that in previous runs, I had selected static IP address, however this remained in /etc/resolv.conf as manual when i reverted the change.

I also found an extra few entries related and named wlan1

My solution:

- Deleted the extra entries as i had only one dongle
- changed the wlan0 entry from manual to dhcp

hope it helps some of us