# Why can I SSH in to my Pi, but can't access the network from it?

Tags: networking, ssh, raspbian-buster, pi-hole

I recently re-arranged my home office, which required unplugging my router and Raspberry Pi 3 (among other things). Despite changing nothing besides the ethernet cable, I am now encountering the following problem.

I am able to SSH into my Raspbery Pi 3 (running Raspbian Buster) from my Windows machine. However, from inside the RPi, I am not able to ping/curl/wget/SSH any network resources:

- Remote domain names (`ping google.com` sends packages but receives none)
- Remote IPs (`ping 1.1.1.1`)
- LAN IPS (`ping 192.168.0.120`, my Windows box)
- The LAN router (`ping 192.168.0.1`)

Each of these operations time out.

### Configuration

#### `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
```

#### `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
hostname 
clientid
persistent
option rapid_commit
option interface_mtu
require dhcp_server_identifier
slaac private

interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.0.64/24
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=127.0.0.1
```

#### Example `ping` to LAN router

```
root@rpi3:~# ping 192.168.0.1
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 190ms
```

#### `ifconfig -a eth0`

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
inet 192.168.0.64  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fe9a:d30f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link> 
ether b8:27:eb:9a:d3:0f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
RX packets 1598  bytes 173011 (168.9 KiB)
RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
TX packets 4178  bytes 434471 (424.2 KiB)
TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

#### `iptables -L`

```
root@rpi3:~# sudo iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

#### `iptables --table nat --list --verbose`

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

#### `routes -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

#### Router information

```
MAC Address:           E4:6F:13:FA:CC:C3
IP Address:            172.103.149.21
Subnet Mask:           255.255.255.192
Default Gateway:       172.103.149.1
Primary DNS Server:    192.168.0.64
Secondary DNS Server:  1.1.1.1
```

[image: Connected client on the router]

### Other information

- I am using this RPi to run PiHole. It was working happily before I re-arranged the office. PiHole is still running but does not function properly, because it cannot send network requests.
- I have the following `crontab`:

```
0 0 * * Sun apt update && apt-upgrade -y
0 0 * * Sun pihole -up
```

### Things I have tried

- Power cycle router and RPi (obviously)
- Remove reserved IP for RPi on the router
- Various configuration changes to `/etc/network/interfaces`, as described [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/9098/wifi-works-ssh-can-connect-but-cannot-connect-out-to-the-internet-cannot-ping).

### My question

How is it possible that I am able to SSH into the RPi and execute all the above commands, but the RPi isn't even able to access hosts on the LAN?

**UPDATE** with info from a comment:
I re-installed Raspberry Pi OS, and verified that everything was working again. After installing PiHole, the problem reproduced. It seems that PiHole has either changed some configuration or one of its dependencies is causing the issue.

Comment: Just checking - my interfaces file does not have `auto lo eth0 iface lo inet loopback iface eth0 inet manual` in it and my interfaces.d directory is empty.  My dhcpcd.conf has the selected external dns servers in it. I have no firewall enabled - almost reads you have.  Check with `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: I have updated the post with `iptables -L` and `routes -n`.

My `interfaces.d` directory is also empty. Is your interfaces file just empty?

Comment: Take all that junk out of /etc/network/interfaces. It should have one line `source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d` **NOTHING ELSE**.

Comment: @Dougie - I reverted the `interfaces` file to have only the one line. No effect. Still can't even ping the router.

Comment: @Milliways - can you please be more specific? "What you have makes no sense" is not constructive. Can you please elaborate on what doesn't make sense, and what would make sense instead?

Comment: Please add the output of this command to the question: `sudo iptables --table nat --list --verbose`. Attach the RasPi direct to the MS Windows box and ssh into the RasPi. Can you `ping 192.168.0.120` from the RasPi?

Comment: Start with a fresh download of RaspiOS Buster

Comment: @Ingo -- I've added the output of that command. I can already SSH into the RPi from my Windows box (connected via router), but can't ping the Windows box from the RPi.

Comment: @Dougie that is looking more and more to be the "solution" -- it would be nice to understand the issue rather than going nuclear though :)

Comment: The suggestion was to direct connect the RasPi to the MS box to eliminate possible problems with your network and the router and check with this direct point to point connection if you can then ping the MS box from the RasPi. It is to reduce possible error sources.

Comment: **Update**: I re-installed Raspberry Pi OS, and verified that everything was working again. After installing PiHole, the problem reproduced. It seems that PiHole has either changed some configuration or one of its dependencies is causing the issue.